# Changing journey builder data extension field name

Tags: journeybuilder, dataextensions

I use a custom preference center so I have to have contact id = id for the field name. However, when using Salesforce Data entry it is pulling in the object name and id for example: Appoint;PersonContactId. Can I change the data extension field name to just ID or will that prevent users from entering the journey?